# 1994 Pathfinder (barely used for 6 months) bogs and then dies. Troublehooting help needed

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, stall, pathfinder

First I must mention the history of my 1994 Pathfinder. I started having problems with start-up with the car 2 years ago.

I took it to a certified mechanic twice and they could find no problem with it.

Then a friend with some car know-how looked at it and said that it wasn't my starter or alternator which I had just replaced. I don't know why this worked but he put in a push button bypass ignition switch and magically all seemed cured for about a year or so. Then all of sudden I was back to periodically having to jump start my car every so often, then it stopped starting altogether.

I then took it into the shop and was told that I had a faulty alternator and it was replaced under warranty. The same shop who couldn't find a reason for my start-up problems yet at this point had put in 1 new starter and 2 new alternator in a span of 2 years. It made no sense to me why this was happening then just months after putting the new alternator in I started having the same startup problems.

Not trusting my usual auto shop after this I consulted another mechanic who told me it's most likely that I have a parasitic leakage somewhere and that it could be likely coming from the aftermarket alarm system that the previous owner installed but to track down the source of the parasitic draw would be costly.

As a stop-gap measure I disconnected the battery when not in use to keep the battery from being drained then bought another car. In every other aspect the Pathfinder ran just fine upon start-up.

It is now 6 months later and I found a buyer for the car. He was made aware that I had these start-up issues before and that it was idle for a while but periodically was started to prevent the engine from freezing up. The buyer decided to get the car anyway. We reconnected the battery and off he went with the car.

A few hours later I get a call saying that the car was running fine until he stopped for lunch then started to drive home. He said it started to bog and then wouldn't start again.

I started an Internet search to find some help and found out that there are certain things that one should do when storing a car that I didn't know and therefore didn't do with my car so my questions for anyone who care to respond are as follows:

1. Does it sound like the car stalled due to extended non-use or as a result of the parasitic leakage? *Note: I never had any problems with the car stalling once its started prior to today.*
2. Could any of the temporary fixes implemented have caused or compounded the problem?
3. Could the old gas in the tank which was only half full caused the bogging and eventual stall out?
4. What can I do to diagnose the problem?
5. How difficult are the possible solutions? I'm feeling very vexed as to what to do. Technically the car is no longer mine, but I feel a sense of responsibility to do something. I'd appreciate any insight into this matter.

Comment: Great level of detail. Please review the [FAQ for starting issues](http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/1518/675). What's not clear at the moment is whether the car cranks but won't start, or does not crank at all.

Comment: The car startrted then would  sputter and die.I passed on to the new owner.  what info I got from this website about possible areas to look into. I haven't heard of anything else going wrong. Hopefully it helped.